# Precise interpretation of $\Vdash \phi$, or "$\phi$ is a tautology"

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus

Let $\Vdash \phi$ denote that $\phi$ is a tautology, *i.e.* that for any valuation $f$, $[\phi]_f = 1$. (Informally, $\phi$ is true no matter what truth value we give to the atoms composing it.)

Let $A \Vdash \phi$ denote that $\phi$ is a *consequence* of $A$, where $A$ is a set of propositional formulas. In other words, let it denote that whenever every $a \in A$ is true (or has a valuation $f$ such that $[a]_f = 1$), it follows that $\phi$ is true as well (or $[\phi]_f =1$).

I was requested to prove

$$
(\Vdash \psi \to \phi) \iff(\{ \psi \} \Vdash \phi)
$$

I am confused with respect to the interpretation of $\Vdash$ as denoting a tautology. Precisely,

$$
\Vdash \psi \to \phi
$$

may mean $a.$ ($\psi \to \phi$) is a tautology; $b$. $\psi$ is a tautology. It seems to me that the second case is correct. But assuming this, a new question arise. Namely, consider the proposition $\Vdash \psi \to \phi$, which reads "if $\psi$ is a tautology then $\phi$ follows". When considering the possible truth values of this proposition, should I

$1.$ Assume $\psi$ is always true (because it is a tautology) and only see how the proposition varies with respect to the truth values of $\phi$; or

$2.$ Consider $\Vdash \psi$ as a formula on itself, which could be true or false?

In short, my doubt boils down to not knowing whether $\Vdash$ is a *notation* declaring that something is the case, or an *operator* (such as $\neg$) which may (along with a proposition) be the case or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\Vdash \psi \to \phi$" should be parsed as $\Vdash (\psi \to \phi)$. It wouldn't make sense to parse it as $(\Vdash \psi) \to \phi$, because $\phi$ is an object (a propositional formula) in our metatheory, not an actual sentence.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me!